# Project does not contain any commands in project.json and cannot be started directly

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx, coreclr

I came across the error when I started the project in Visual Studio 2015.
[image]

My project.json file:

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0-*",
   "description": "xxxxEngine Class Library",
   "authors": [ "somebody" ],
   "tags": [ "" ],
   "projectUrl": "",
   "licenseUrl": "",
   "frameworks": {
   "dnx451": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
      "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
      "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Stateless": "2.5.53",
    "xxx.yyy": "1.0.0-*"
  }
}
```

And here is my DNVM list:

[image: DNVM]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least one command in the `project.json` file, similar to what's in the file [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/MusicStore/project.json#L45-L51):

```
"commands": {
  "gen": "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration",
  "run": "run server.urls=http://localhost:5003",
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004",
  "weblistener": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5002"
}
```

That's because you run `dnx <command>` where command is one of the commands in the project file